# Override property with instance field

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to implement caching of value returned from database:

```
class Foo

...

    def getTag(self):
        value = self._Db.get(self._f[F_TAG])

        setattr(self, 'tag', value)

        return value

    def _setTag(self, tag):
        self._Db.set(self._f[F_TAG], tag)


    tag = property(getTag)

...

x = Foo()        

x._setTag("20")
print(x.tag)
x._setTag("40")
print(x.tag)
```

When I first time handle **tag** property, it must get value from DB and override *class* field **tag** with *instance* field for following use, but error occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/altera/www/autoblog/core/dbObject.py", line 99, in <module>
    print(x.tag)
  File "/home/altera/www/autoblog/core/dbObject.py", line 78, in getTag
    setattr(self, 'tag', value)
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it's impossible to override a `@property`. This is because the `@property` is attached to the class, not the instance.

You can either make your `@property` getter slightly more complex:

```
@property
def tag(self):
    try:
        return self._db_values["tag"]
    except KeyError:
        pass
   val = self._db.get("tag")
   self._db_values["tag"] = val
   return val
```

Or create a descriptor which will do the caching for you:

```
Undefined = object()

class DBValue(object):
    def __init__(self, column_name):
        self.column_name = column_name
        self.value = Undefined

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        if self.value is Undefined:
            self.value = instance._db.get(self.column_name)
        return self.value

class Foo(object):
    tag = DBValue("tag")
```

Comment: I'm tried to use *__dict__* but this does not work, I mean after key *tag* has been added, the *getTag* function still invokes.

OK, I'll think :) I wanted to do something like function replacing in .NET JIT compiler :)

Comment: OK, I understand. But using descriptors for me is less flexible solution. T think I'll use your first example

Comment: Why are descriptors less flexible? The `@property` decorator *is* a descriptor… ;)

Comment: Yes, I know, but your *DBValue* descriptor in my case is less flexible.

Comment: Sure… But it's just an example, which you could extend to do whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Your `x.tag` is a property and doesn't have a setter, so when you try to set it, you get an error for the obvious reason. So store the actual value in a "private" field such as `x._tag` and write a getter and setter for it.

```
class Foo(object):

    _tag = None

    @property
    def tag(self):
        if self._tag is None:
            self._tag = self._Db.get(self._f[F_TAG])
        return self._tag

    @tag.setter
    def tag(self, tag):
        self._tag = tag
        self._Db.set(self._f[F_TAG], tag)

x = Foo()
print x.tag    # gets the value from the database (if necessary) or f._tag
x.tag = "bar"  # sets the value in the database and caches it in f._tag
```

Comment: I now that setter was not defined, I don't need it.
I want to OVERRIDE class property *Foo.tag* in *x.tag* with local (instance) value *x.tag*

Comment: Again, you're trying to assign a property (`x.tag`), which *isn't going to work* if it doesn't have a setter. The fact that you *want* to do it doesn't mean it'll magically start working.

Comment: I remember, there is an example of descriptors overriding in *Mark Lutz - Learning Python* (4 Edition) somewhere in chapter 37 (Managed Attributes)